# How to extend the days in a Week from 7 to 8

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I know this is absurd. There is 7 days in a week, but I do have a requirement that needs to have 8 days extending the range a little bit. So far, I created a date table in DAX which looks like this.

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3WEi.png)

Highlighted in the last row it shows 28/08/2023 as Week Ending 3/09/2023.
I was looking for a way to include this in WE 27/08/2023.
Extending the range From Monday to Monday but no luck. Haven't tried in PQ side.
Any ideas how we can execute this type of request?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  "8 Day Ending", [Date] + 7 - MOD([Date] - DATE(2023, 8, 27) - 1, 8)
```

Adjust `DATE(2023, 8, 27)` to a known or desired "Ending" date.

Note - in your screenshot example - 28/08/2023 can't have an end date of 27/08/2023, as it, itself is the end date, so all the ones above should of had 28/08/2023 as their end.